# How to change background color of Autocomplete Listbox in Winform Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

I want to change the **Background Color** of the **Suggestion Listbox**. When we type on the combobox, the suggestion listbox will open. I want to change its color same as the combobox's background. By default its background color is white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is to develop your own control, as the combobox not allowed to change the color of suggestion list.
On this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8619/Flat-MultiColumn-Combobox-with-Autocomplete  you have a similar example, a combobox that lets you search for columns and also allows you to change the color of the suggestion list.